# Error 'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767

Tags: python, python-3.x, sas, anaconda, format

This is the error I'm getting when I'm trying to convert .cvs file to .xpt (sas format)
I don't know why this error is coming, do we need to specify format of anything if yes how to do that.
When I run the same thing with just 500 or 600 rows of data I get the output but when I run for full file which is around 35000 rows I get this error.
if you have any idea on this please let me know..
Library used are...

```
import xport
import xport.v56
import pandas as pd
```

```
xpot --version ==> 3.2.1
```

```
error: 'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Please share a sample of your csv file as well